# name 'get_total_discount_item_price' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get the total price of all the items. But this error pops out whenever I try to do it. What can that due to? It says that the name is not defined even though I've written it and it should perform the task correctly.

This is the HTML code:

```
{% for object in orders %}
            <div class="row justify-content-start">
                <div class="col col-lg-5 col-md-6 mt-5 cart-wrap ftco-animate">
                    <div class="cart-total mb-3">
                        <h3>Cart Totals</h3>
                        <p class="d-flex">
                            <span>Subtotal</span>
                {% if object.get_total %}


                <span>  ${{ object.get_total }}</span>
                        </p>
               {% endif %}
                        <p class="d-flex">
                            <span>Delivery</span>
                            <span>$0.00</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="d-flex">
                            <span>Discount</span>
                            <span>$3.00</span>
                        </p>
                        <hr>
                        <p class="d-flex total-price">
                            <span>Total</span>
                            <span>$17.60</span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <p class="text-center"><a href="{% url 'core:checkout' %}" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-4">Proceed to Checkout</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

this is the models.py:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.item.title}"

    def get_total_item_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.item.price

    def get_total_discount_item_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.item.discount_price

    def get_final_price(self):
        if self.item.discount_price:
            return get_total_discount_item_price()
        return self.get_total_item_price()

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_total(self):
        total = 0
        for order_item in self.items.all():
            total += order_item.get_final_price()
        return total
```

views.py:

```
def cart(request):
    context = {'items': OrderItem.objects.all(), 'orders': Order.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'ecommerceapp/cart.html', context)
```

Thank you for any help. I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to put "self" before the function. check this:

```
def get_final_price(self):
    if self.item.discount_price:
        return self.get_total_discount_item_price()
    return self.get_total_item_price()
```

Answer (score 0):

append self. in front of `get_total_discount_item_price()`